# rewriteCond request with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I would like to accomplish the followings (rewrite not redirect):

1. `searchPage.php?crs_category=variable` like `searchPage.php?crs_category=business` to `category/business` or `category/business/` case in-sensitive

You can also directly access `category/name` which is the rewrite of searchPage

2. `index.php/name` to `page/name` case in-sesitive. note this is a rewrite not a redirect and i would like access the `index.php/name` just with a clean url.

You can also directly access `page/name` which is the rewrite of `index.php/name`

Note:
- it needs to take into account spaces such as if a user click on `searchPage.php?crs_category=html%20and%css` it would rewrite the url to `category/html and css`

Tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage.php\?crs_category=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/%1? [NE,NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ /searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1 [NE,R,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Problem:
For some reason the request doesn't work for these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage.php\?crs_category=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/%1? [NE,NC,R,L]
```

In addition, I am not sure who take into account white space. where if its `searchPage.php?crs_category=html%20andcss` it leads to category/html and css disregarding the spacing code

Update:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage\.php\?crs_category=([^&]+?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1? [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1 [NE,R,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: So, is this about redirecting *old* `index.php?page=…` to the newer `page/…` scheme? Or just mapping the new to the PHP handler? Also did you really want to have `/page/` case-insensitive as well?

Comment: thanks for your response. i am using slim framework. the link is actually index.php/page where page is the variable name like index.php/about or index.php/faq and not index.php?page= its mapping the new to the php handler, or other words masking the index.php/about url with page/about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be matching `/` after `index.php` not `?`:

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage\.php\?crs_category=([^&]+?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1? [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1 [NE,R,L]

# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(\S*)\s+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^(\S+)$ $1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks. I realize that this question was complex than i thought and have include an update version under my initial post. thanks in advance

Comment: also i feel like your suggest answer is a redirect rather than a url rewrite

Comment: yeah my fault. i should of clarified. I have rewritten my post accoridngly

Comment: thanks. one thing i notice with your revised code is that it cuts the rewrite string for instance when you click searchPage.php?crs_category=Microsoft it gives you category/Micro. or searchPage.php?crs_category= or searchPage.php?crs_category=databases%20and%20business%20intelligence gives you category/databa

Comment: thanks for sticking along. i think were almost there.the full url is written such category/microsoft instead of the cut category/Micro but the spacing chracter %20 is still present such as if you type searchPage.php?crs_category=web%20development it should turnout as category/web development

Comment: `%20` is indeed space in URLs. Inside `searchPage.php` when you use `$_GET['crs_category']` it will indeed show `web development`. You can test it.

Comment: i've given you credit due to all the amount of work. i know %20 is space but i want the %20 to be hidden in the url rewrite and just show category/web development without the space character code

Comment: is there any rules to hide the %20 from the public eye?

Comment: how about we replace %20 with the dash - such as html-and-css i just think it would look more professional that way thank you so much

Comment: thank you. i've tried to integrate it but dont think ive executed it properly. i've added an update under my initial post.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. I notice it only work for two letters such as web development which becomes web-development but pass 2 words the dash rewrite doesn't to rewrite if i change NOSPACE to =3 for instance would it allow up to 4 words?

Comment: No I have tested it for `searchPage.php?crs_category=databases%20and%20business%20intelligence` and it worked fine and converted all to hyphens. I need to be offline now as it is 4AM here. Also I think space to hyphen is unrelated problem from your original question and we should not have such a long comments over that.